# Should a dict that I use only once during initialization be put inside my class?

Tags: python, class, coding-style

I only need to use operatorDict one time to determine which operation I am using for the class. What is the most pythonic way to store the correct operator inside of self._f ?

```
class m:
    def __init__(self,n,operator,digit1,digit2):
        self._operatorDict = {'+':add, '-':sub, 'x':mul, '/':truediv}
        self._f = self._operatorDict[operator]
        self._score = 0
        self._range = n
        self._aMin, self._aMax = getMaxMinDigits(digit1)
        self._bMin, self._bMax = getMaxMinDigits(digit2)
```

Comment: Store it as a class attribute maybe?

Comment: A note on naming -- If you stick with python long-term, you'll be better off if you condition yourself to use pep8 names now.  e.g. `class M` and `operator_dict`.

Comment: Also pep8 whitespace! https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Need to start reading through that material. Oh it is so dry, but will be worth it in the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much of this depends on how much of the operatorDict you want to expose.  In this case, I'd probably recommend one of two things.

#### Option 1: Put the dict on the class:

```
class m:
    _operatorDict = {'+':add, '-':sub, 'x':mul, '/':truediv}

    def __init__(self,n,operator,digit1,digit2):
        self._f = self._operatorDict[operator]
        self._score = 0
        self._range = n
        self._aMin, self._aMax = getMaxMinDigits(digit1)
        self._bMin, self._bMax = getMaxMinDigits(digit2)
```

Since the `_operatorDict` isn't going to mutate inside the class, it doesn't really seem necessary to have it as a instance attribute.  However, it still belongs to the class in some sense.  This approach also allows you to change the `operatorDict` as necessary (e.g. in a subclass).

#### Option 2: Put the dict in the global namespace:

```
_operatorDict = {'+':add, '-':sub, 'x':mul, '/':truediv}

class m:

    def __init__(self,n,operator,digit1,digit2):
        self._f = _operatorDict[operator]
        self._score = 0
        self._range = n
        self._aMin, self._aMax = getMaxMinDigits(digit1)
        self._bMin, self._bMax = getMaxMinDigits(digit2)
```

The advantages here are similar to before -- mainly that you only create one operatorDict and not one per instance of `m`.  It's also a little more rigid in that this form doesn't really allow for easy changing of the `operatorDict` via subclassing.  In some cases, this rigidity can be desirable.  Also, as some noted in the comments, if you use this second option, naming `_operatorDict` to indicate that it is a constant in your naming system (e.g. `_OPERATOR_DICT` in pep8) is probably a good idea.

Comment: If he does opt for using your second option, I'd suggest making `_operatorDict` a constant; `OPERATOR_DICT`. To me, this would make the meaning much more clear.

Comment: @leaf -- Agreed.  However, OP isn't using pep 8 names, so it isn't immediately clear to me that `_OPERATOR_DICT` would mean constant in that naming system ;-)